# Can I superimose a ggplot heatmap on a geographic map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, heatmap

I have a heatmap (geom_tile) with geographic coordinates on the x and y axes, and I would like to place a simple geographic map behind the heatmap. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This R-Bloggers post covers the using `geom_tile()` with data extracted from `maps::` for use in `geom_map()`:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/05/mapping-tornado-alley-with-r/

The `map_data()`  function is another way to extract data from `maps::`.

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/map_data.html

You will need to post more details, code, data, and/or a reproducible example to go deeper.